# Unit test error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular

I started looking into unit testing angular 2 applications, but I'm stuck even in the simplest examples. I just want to run a simple test to see if it even works, basically what I want is to compare a value from the title page to the one in the test.

This is the error I'm getting, but I don't see where the error is coming from since everything looks to be synchronous to me.

> Error: Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test.

Unit test:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, Input}    from '@angular/core';
import { ToDoComponent } from './todo.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
describe(("test input "),() => {
    let comp:    ToDoComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ToDoComponent>;
    let de:      DebugElement;
    let el:      HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ ToDoComponent ],
            imports: [ FormsModule ]
        })
        .compileComponents();  
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ToDoComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("h1"));
    el = de.nativeElement;

    it('should display a different test title', () => {
        comp.pageTitle = 'Test Title';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toBe('Test Title423');
    });
});
```

My component:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Note} from "app/note";

@Component({
    selector : "toDoArea",
    templateUrl : "todo.component.html"
})

export class ToDoComponent{
    pageTitle : string = "Test";
    noteText : string ="";
    noteArray : Note[] = [];
    counter : number = 1;
    removeCount : number = 1;

    addNote() : void {

        if (this.noteText.length > 0){
            var a = this.noteText;
            var n1 : Note = new Note();
            n1.noteText = a;
            n1.noteId = this.counter;
            this.counter = this.counter + 1;
            this.noteText = "";
            this.noteArray.push(n1);        
        }

    }

    removeNote(selectedNote : Note) :void{
        this.noteArray.splice(this.noteArray.indexOf(selectedNote),this.removeCount);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Move your variable initialization inside a beforeEach.

You shouldn't be getting things out of the TestBed or managing the fixture or component in the `describe` scope. You should only do these things within the scope of a test run: inside a `beforeEach`/`beforeAll`, `afterEach`/`afterAll`, or inside an `it`.

```
describe(("test input "), () => {
  let comp: ToDoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ToDoComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ToDoComponent],
        imports: [FormsModule]
      })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ToDoComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("h1"));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  })


  it('should display a different test title', () => {
    comp.pageTitle = 'Test Title';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toBe('Test Title423');
  });

});
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#waiting-compile-components

Comment: This example is correct, but the comment doesn't address the issue you had.

compileComponents() is an asynchronous function to read the HTML template, so it requires the async test zone (set up by the async() in the first beforeEach).

The second beforeEach is guaranteed to run only after the first one has completed (a bit non-obvious, but helpful). Another option is to use a .then() on compileComponents, since it returns a promise.

Note that if you are using webpack (Angular CLI) or some some other mechanism to bundle component templates, you don't need to call compileComponents().

Comment: In my case, I got this error when executing test code in a `describe` block instead of an `it` block.

Answer (score 26):

I got the same error for a different reason. I put a `TestBed.get(Dependency)` call within a `describe` block. The fix was moving it to the `it` block.

Wrong:

```
describe('someFunction', () => {
    const dependency = TestBed.get(Dependency); // this was causing the error

    it('should not fail', () => {
        someFunction(dependency);
    });
});
```

Fixed:

```
describe('someFunction', () => {
    it('should not fail', () => {
        const dependency = TestBed.get(Dependency); // putting it here fixed the issue
        someFunction(dependency);
    });
});
```

Comment: `TestBed.get()` method is deprecated since Angular 9.0.0, `TestBed.inject()` should be used instead.