# Karma jasmine test angular 5 cannot call Promise

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am new to karma jasmine test and I am struggling with a test that always gives  this error when I launch the test:

> Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test.

I am using angular 5. Here is my test code:

```
fdescribe('CommentComponent', () => {
  let component: CommentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CommentComponent>;
  let commentService: CommentService;
  const stationId = 900;
  let station: Station;
  let comment: Comment;

  beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    station = new Station();
    station.id = stationId;
    comment = new Comment('', null, null, '');

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        CommentComponent,

      ],
      providers: [
        CommentService,
        StationService,
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        NgxPaginationModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CommentComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }));
  afterEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    component = null;
    fixture.destroy();
    commentService = null;
    comment = null;
  }));

  commentService = TestBed.get(CommentService);
  it('should create', async() => {
    tick(1000);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here is my component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment',
  templateUrl: './comment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comment.component.css']
})
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('newCommentForm') form;
  params: Params;
  comment: Comment = new Comment('', null, null, '');
  comments = [];
  constructor(private commentService: CommentService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.params = params);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getComment();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.commentService.saveComment(this.comment.text, this.params['id']).subscribe(
      comment => this.comment = comment,
      error => this.onErrorSave(error) ,
      () => this.onCompleteSave()
    );
  }

  getComment(): void {
    this.commentService.getComments(this.params['id']).subscribe(
      comments => this.comments = comments,
      error => console.error(error),
      () => console.log('Commentaires chargés')
    );
  }
  onErrorSave(error) {
    this.snackBar.open(errorMessageConnection, 'Close', {
      duration: 3000
    });
    console.error(error);
  }
  onCompleteSave() {
    this.snackBar.open(sendingMsgCommentSucces, 'Close', {
      duration: 3000
    });
    console.log('Commentaire sauvegardé');
    this.form.reset();
    this.getComment();
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me it would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit test error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186533/unit-test-error-cannot-call-promise-then-from-within-a-sync-test)

Answer (score 2):

Your test, as it is right now, is synchronous meaning that, as soon as the scope of the test ends, the test is over and karma/jasmine.

You need to write [asynchronous tests](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-42).  Supply `it()` with a callback they you can use to signal that the test is over.

```js
describe("Should be async", () => {
  it("can call promises", done => {
    someAsyncThing().then(() => {
      done()
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I would try that