# AuthGuard Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I have tried to test a guard component  in Angular 10. The component has injected service which

An error message: "Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test.". Maybe someone knows what is wrong?

```
    import { TestBed, waitForAsync, async, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  let guard: AuthGuard;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let authService: AuthService;
  const routerMock = {navigate: jasmine.createSpy('chats')};

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [AuthGuard, { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock }],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
    guard = TestBed.inject(AuthGuard);
  });

  injector = getTestBed();
  authService = injector.inject(AuthService);
  guard = injector.inject(AuthGuard);

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it('should redirect an unauthenticated user to the login route', waitForAsync(() => {
    const promise = new Promise(() => {});
    promise.then(() => {
        expect(authService.SignOut).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }));

  it('should allow the authenticated user to access app', waitForAsync(() => {
    const promise = new Promise(() => {});
    promise.then(() => {
        expect(authService.isLoggedIn).toBe(true);
    });
  }));
});
```

can you help me please thanks

Answer (score 0):

To cut it short: you should move your initialization of routerMock into the beforeEach() block.

This issue has already been discussed:
[Unit test error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186533/unit-test-error-cannot-call-promise-then-from-within-a-sync-test)